# Different content in same blocks through different contexts

Tags: blocks, theming, 7

This is probably simple and has likely has already been asked but I can't find it anywhere else on here.

I currently have context, delta, and omega installed.  I'm currently using the content block to hold my slider on the home page but it keeps on showing up everywhere throughout the site.

Same for the postscript first and second blocks.  I have two different views in there and they keep showing up throughout the site, everywhere those blocks exist.

My question is, is it possible for me to fill those blocks with different content, or should I create my own blocks for the home page instead?

Also, is there a good video tutorial somewhere on using delta and context or just basic page ordering in drupal?

Thanks,

Comment: This link will be helpful to You                          http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/context/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this through using [delta](https://drupal.org/project/delta).  What's not mentioned above is that I was using Omega 3 when I had this problem.  I've not used it yet, but I believe Omega 4 handles this differently.